# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: reactjs

Check the render method of `App`.

I am trying to use Context Api I have App component and it returns Component1 which has  nested component .I thought since I wrap  Component1 inside of  ContextApi.Provider ,all it's nested components should see value passed  as a prop to the contextApi. I am  getting the same error every time I  wrap element inside of ContextApi.

Here is the App Component:

```
   import logo from './logo.svg';
   import './App.css';
   import Component1 from '../src/Component1/Component1'
   import ContextApi from '../src/context-api'

    function App() {
      return (
      <ContextApi.Provider   value={{
         name :"PARVIZ PIRIZADA"
 
       }}>
      <Component1></Component1> 
   </ContextApi.Provider>
  );
}
          export default App;
```

Here is the Component1

```
import NestedComponent from '../NestedComponent/NestedComponent'
 function Component1 (){
 return <NestedComponent></NestedComponent>  //nested component inside of Component1
        }
   export default Component1
```

Here is the   NestedComponent

```
import ContextApi from '../context-api'
 export default function  NestedComponent(){
    return <ContextApi.Consumer>   // here I am trying to get value in contextApi as an consumer
    {(ctx)=>{
        return <div> {ctx.name}</div>
    }}
     </ContextApi.Consumer>
```

}

Here is my ContextApi

```
  import  React from   'react'
  export default function Context(){
   return React.createContext({
    name : "PARVIZ"
})
```

}

Comment: Where is the error pointing to? If I were you I'd start commenting out things to find what exactly is causing the error. Hard to tell from the partial information given here.

Comment: it is pointing to React.render()   in index.js